# installation of fedora 26 : partitions configuration not accepted

Tags: fedora, partition

I would like to configure the installation of fedora 26 but I have some issues.
I have 2 disks:

- sdb which is a 120Go SSD disk
- sda, a 1To normal sata disk

I have got windows installed on the SSD disk.

I want to put the /home directory in sda (100Go should suffice) and everything else in sdb.
so I configured the fedora installer as follow:

[image: sda]
and [image: sdb]

but this configuration seems not be good for fedora : the installer says that "you have to create a new filesystem on the root device"... I don't understand what is it complaining about.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok, solved : the root partition need to be mounted as "/" and also to be given a name. Give it a name solved my problem.